# Rounding issue - From nanoseconds to minute

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to round datetime series from nanoseconds to minutes?

```
df2["t_stamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df2["t_stamp"])
print(df2["t_stamp"])
```

Output:

```
>>2017-11-07 12:30:35.937000
>>2017-11-07 14:19:10.497000
>>2017-11-07 12:31:52.337000 
>>..
```

What I want to reach now is:

```
>>2017-11-07 12:31
>>2017-11-07 14:19
>>2017-11-07 12:32 
>>..
```

I tried something like this, but this has no effect on the output at all:

```
df2["t_stamp_rounded"] = df2["t_stamp"].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour,round(float(dt.minute))))
```

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas' `round()` method.

```
print(df2['t_stamp'].dt.round('min').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

0    2017-11-07 12:31
1    2017-11-07 14:19
2    2017-11-07 12:32
Name: t_stamp, dtype: object
```